# Visual Studio 2015 not responding

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have recently installed Windows 10 in my DELL laptop. I see quite often Visual Studio 2015 not responding.

Is there a **log** that I can turn on to see what's happening in the **Visual Studio** while loading a project, to see any add-on delaying the load? Or something like that in the **Task Monitor** to see which resource is causing the slowness like disk read or memory?

[image]

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:

As per IInspectable's comment, I created a dump file from the Task Manager.

I don't see any thread information in this file. I tried to debug (by clicking debug from the actions menu) after loading the data in VS 2015 again. That takes a while to load the symbols, but at the end I see *Source Not Available* screen and stop there.

11/18/2015: Asp.net tools team is working on this [performance](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/152#issuecomment-146158390) issue.

Comment: Create a minidump, when an application is no longer responding (e.g. by switching to *Task Manager*'s *Processes* tab, rightclicking the respective process and choosing *Create dump file*). The dump can then be loaded into a debugger, allowing to inspect the threads. Since the *"Not Responding"* is caused by GUI threads failing to respond to messages, you already know which threads to concentrate on. Microsoft provides public symbols for all relevant system DLLs, making the call stacks actually useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try enabling logging via the /Log command line option of the devenv.exe. See the Microsoft [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx). (devenv.exe being the Visual Studio IDE)

Comment: "Is there a log that I can turn on to see what's happening in the Visual Studio while loading a project, to see any add-on delaying the load?"

Comment: David, Welcome to [so]! Short answers are unfortunately likely to be mistaken for bad answers, due to the process in place. Including relevant information from your link would have avoided this trap, and perhaps make for an even better answer.